# How to make the Music App on macOS 12 save changed settings when closed?

Tags: macos, itunes, music

I recently upgraded my older iMac 2015 to macOS 12. Now I noticed the Music App does not save any settings I made while using Music, i.e. if I change the width of the left column this setting is lost when closing Music, the column is the same size as at last start. Or the last selected section/playlist will be lost too, Music starts at the same point every time on open.

I assume there is a settings file or database where all those settings will be saved on closing the app, but I am not able to find this file.

Is there anything I can do to have Music save the settings?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this on 12.3.1 and it does save the width of the sidebar and shows the last selected playlist for me. So it should work if everything is working ok.

Try quitting Music and move

```
/Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Music.plist
```

to the Desktop. This is where Music saves its settings. It will create a new Settings file in `~/Library/Preferences` on launch, maybe it became corrupted. You will lose any custom "Settings" like playback preferences though.

Playlists are stored elsewhere so you won't lose those.

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately doesn't work. Any other ideas? TIA